# Best practice of Rails + Angular e2e tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, integration-testing, single-page-application, angularjs-e2e

We are developing an enterprise (single page) application using Rails as back-end and Angular as front-end.

We don't have any problem regarding the back-end tests but writing integration tests for Angular is not easy. We have to simulate the back-end API.

What is the best practices for functional/integration/e2e tests of the front-end of a single page application?

Comment: A unit test would usually simulate back end API's. An e2e test in Angular shouldn't do that. That's the whole point, right?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a classic problem. I ended up using the VCR gem and doing my integration tests on the rails side.

Comment: To further my comment, Angular provides `$httpBackend` to make assertions on how your code interacts w/the server. This is where you would fake success/fail responses w/your API in a unit test. Contrast that with Protractor (also from Angular) which uses Selenium to automate interaction with your actual web UI. <-- that is e2e in Angular.

Comment: @SunilD. I don't agree. We can have automated tests in every level though the speed and the quality of the tests would be different. As rails support integration tests as simple as possible. It's possible in Angular, I just looking for the best practices.

Comment: @AmirKarimi yes Rails has great support for integration testing, it wasn't meant for an SPA, however. Protractor is aware of Angular digest cycles, bindings, and other stuff that you'd spend too much time working around otherwise. With Angular we use Rails only for the restful API's. We mostly test our models in Rails. On the client we have unit tests for business logic, and then Protractor tests for e2e/integration tests w/a real backend.